# Setup permanent bridge for dynamic network devices from lxc container?

Tags: bridge, lxc

TL:DR
How can I make a bridge permanent (survive reboot) without adding a network device to the bridge config in /etc/network/interfaces?

Hi, I just started playing around with lxc on ubuntu 14.04.

The setup I would like to accomplish is, one container with haproxy, one with nginx.

I will dnat external requests via iptables to the haproxy and from there to nginx.

All of the containers will be in their own subnet. Routing/packetfiltering between the containers will be done by the host.

I've managed half of the setup so far.

I created two bridges with brctl and added IPs to the bridges.

```
br-haproxy: 10.100.0.1/24
br-nginx: 10.100.3.1/24
```

I then added the respective bridge to the corresponding container via the lxc config.

```
nginx got br-nginx
haproxy got br-haproxy
```

Then I configured IP addresses in the containers.

```
haproxy: 10.100.0.10/24 GW 10.100.0.1
nginx: 10.100.3.10/24 GW 10.100.3.1
```

I was now able to ping between the two containers and so on.
I now denied access by setting the forward policy from iptables to deny.
I was now able to control traffic between the two containers via iptables.

Ok so far so good. What I now want to achieve is, make the bridges permanent.
I added the bridgeconfig to /etc/network/interfaces but since I don't have a network device to add to the bridge I left this part out.

When I now try to initiate the bridge I get an error stating that the device e.g. br-haproxy couldn't be found.

I figured out, that the problem is the missing device in the bridge config. When I add eth0 from the host to the bridge config I can initiate the bridge and it comes up quite nice. But that's not what I need.

LXC dynamically creates and adds the interfaces from the container on startup of the container to the corresponding bridge.

So here comes my question. How can I make the bridges permanent without adding a network device to the bridge on boot?

Hope I made it somewhow clear what the problem is. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I then added the respective bridge to the corresponding container via the lxc config.*: could you please comment on how you did this configuration (I have this exact question pending)

Comment: Hm, I gues you mean the network config for a lxc container. Here is some sort of template I use. # Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.link = br-squid
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.100.2.10/24 <-- you need to adjust the ip
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 10.100.2.1 <-- and here as well
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:b4:7d:43 <-- will be created automatically on creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if you use `bridge_ports none` to get this working on boot, without the need to add members to this interface?

```
auto br-haproxy
iface br-haproxy inet static
       bridge_ports none
       bridge_fd 0 
       bridge_waitport 0
       address 10.100.0.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`bridge_fd` and `waitport` are set to avoid forwarding delay whenever a member port is put online, and avoid delay on waiting a port to be online.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick. You're the best. Didn't know that there was an argument like "none". Should have thought about that. Works like a charm. Solved. :-)

Comment: Yeah. I have to crawl through websites to find out this option, that is not documented at all. :P