# How to bind an lxc container to a specific bridge?

Tags: bridge, lxc, lxd

I created a specific bridge `br1` and would like to bind a specific container `cont1` to that bridge. I have `lxc` and `lxd` installed, if that matters (I am not sure what the difference between them really is).

I disabled the briging to `lxcbr0` in `/etc/default-lxc-net` and created the `/var/lib/lxc/cont1/config` file with

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br1
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.10.11.0/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 10.10.11.11
```

but `lxc cont1 start` fails with (among other log info)

```
lxc 20160313185746.671 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:instantiate_veth:2590 - failed to attach 'vethM1YGJS' to the bridge 'lxcbr0': Operation not permitted
lxc 20160313185746.741 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_create_network:2867 - failed to create netdev
lxc 20160313185746.741 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1023 - failed to create the network
lxc 20160313185746.741 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1286 - failed to spawn 'cont1'
```

It [looks like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252339/64753) that there is a command (?) to make this configuration but I found no documentation on that subject.

Comment: Right now I have the same issue! I am working on it! Will update you if I can get it up. Since it's already a year, I think you would have got some solution. Update it here if you are out of this issue!